# Characters and conjugacy classes

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

This comes up in reading David Speyer's answer to [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/607/non-conjugate-words-with-the-same-trace) Given a finite group $G$ and two non-conjugate elements $x, y,$ how does one construct a unitary representation $\rho$ of $G$ such that $\rho(x)$ and $\rho(y)$ have different traces? (The same question makes sense for infinite groups, but it is far from clear that this is always possible in the infinite setting, even if you drop "unitary").

Comment: I originally answered with "the regular representation" (because all irreds appear in it) but that is silly since trace of non identity g on reg is 0. Sorry about that!

Comment: For infinite groups there are examples of groups that have no finite-dimensional representations whatsoever (e.g. simple groups of cardinality strictly larger than the continuum).

Comment: We can try to use the action of $G$ on $G/\langle y \rangle$ (i.e. the induced representation of the trivial representation of $\langle y \rangle$). If this doesn't work, then $x$ and $y$ fix the same number of cosets of $\langle y \rangle$. So $x$ fixes some coset of $\langle y \rangle$, and thus some conjugate of $x$ belongs to $\langle y \rangle$. We might as well say $x \in \langle y \rangle$. At this point, I think using the induced representation of some other representation of $\langle y \rangle$ should do, but I can't quite finish the argument.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: there are indeed such groups, but cardinality has nothing to do here; for instance $SL_n$ of a field of cardinal greater than continuum has a faithful finite-dimensional representation. On the other hand, finitely generated simple groups have no nontrivial finite-dimensional representation over any field (and over any commutative ring as well).

Comment: @AntonMalyshev : I think you need to induce a faithful $1$-dimensional representation of $\langle y \rangle.$ Then your argument has a better chance of working, though I don't see all details.

Comment: For infinite groups unitary irreducible representations seperate points: [Gelfand-Raikov theorem](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gelfand-Raikov+theorem)

Comment: Igor, I think you need to make it clearer what you are looking for. When asking about algorithms for finite groups, the two most common situations are firstly, I have some specific examples that I want to compute, and secondly I want to know the complexity of the best known algorithm for this. Do either of those apply to you? If the group is not too big, then I would just compute its character table to find the character of a suitable $\rho$ and then use that to find $\rho$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the deleted post by George McNinch was on the right track, at least if one knows the central idempotents of the group algebra $\mathbb{C}G.$ If take the regular module $\mathbb{C}G$ (which affords a unitary representation with resepect to the standard basis of group elements), then the central idempotent $e_{\chi},$ associated to the irreducible character $\chi,$ is represented by a diagonal idempotent matrix of trace $\chi(1)^{2}.$
The right $\mathbb{C}G$ module $e_{\chi}\mathbb{C}$ affords a unitary representation with character $\chi(1) \chi.$ For some choice of $\chi,$ we have $\chi(x) \neq \chi(y),$ so the representation afforded by $e_{\chi} \mathbb{C}G$ will do.

Comment: Is there a good way of finding the central idempotent for a given irreducible representation? This is classical in the symmetric group case but I don't know of an algorithm that can do this in generality.

Comment: Right, Geoff. Somehow what I thought the OP was fishing for was an *a priori* construction of a representation with the indicated property. I'm not sure I see precisely why $e_\chi \mathbf{C}G$ is more accessible than just "the representation affording the irreducible character $\chi$".

Comment: @Siddarth Venkatesh : An answer of sorts is that the module $e_{\lambda}\mathbb{C}G$ is the intersection of certain eigenspaces of class sums when acting on the regular module.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can always do this by taking a rep of the cyclic group generated by $x$, and inducing this up to the whole group. (**EDIT**: I should mention that this was suggested in comments.) If $y$ is not conjugate to a power of $x$, the trivial will suffice.  If $y$ is a power of $x$, then some non-trivial 1-dimensional representation of $\langle x\rangle$ will work.

Let $n$ be the order of $x$.  The action of the normalizer of $\langle x\rangle$ by conjugation on this subgroup gives a map to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ with kernel its centralizer.  Let $U$ be the image of this map.  We just have to choose a representation where the character values of $x$ and $y$ (which are $n$th roots of unity) aren't conjugate under $U$ acting as a subgroup of the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}[e^{2\pi i/n}]$.  If they are always conjugate, that precisely shows that $x$ and $y$ are conjugate as elements of the group.